# Prevent Multiple words in <p> from being separated

Tags: html, string, line-breaks

I'm building a website and ran into a problem where I don't even know what term to google. The problem is very simple: I have a phone number with spaces inside a larger text in `<p>...</p>` and want to prevent it from being split at the end of a line. Example:

```
In urgent cases call +999 123  
45 67 or try one of...
```

and I want either

```
In urgent cases call +999 123 45 67 
or try one of...
```

or

```
In urgent cases call  
+999 123 45 67 or try one of...
```

So how can I achieve this? Manual line break with `<br>` or so is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the number in an element with [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

```
In urgent cases call <span class="phone">+999 123 45 67</span> or try one of...
```

Then add this to your CSS:

```
.phone {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for! Works like a charm and now it's displaying correctly on any device.